# Critique my proof: Proving that $C[a,b]$ is not a Hilbert Space under $L^2$ norm.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, complete-spaces

**So, I would appreciate any critiques I can get for my proof of the following problem.**

The Problem:

Let $[a.b]$ be the closed, bounded interval of real numbers. Show that the $L^2[a,b]$ inner product is also an inner product on $C[a,b]$. Is $C[a,b]$ considered as an inner product space with the $L^2[a,b]$ inner product, a Hilbert space?

*Proof*:
To prove that the inner product of the $L^2[a,b]$ space is also the inner product of the $C[a,b]$ space of continuous functions on $[a,b]$, We check that the three properties of the inner product hold on $C[a,b]$.

(i) \begin{align*}
    \langle \alpha x_1+\beta x_2, y\rangle &=\int^b_a \left(\alpha x_1+\beta x_2\right)y=\int^b_a\alpha x_1\cdot y+\int^b_a\beta x_2\cdot y\\
    &=\alpha\int^b_a x_1\cdot y+\beta\int^b_a x_2\cdot y=\alpha\langle x_1,y\rangle+\beta\langle x_2,y\rangle.
    \end{align*}
(ii) 
    \begin{align*}
\langle x,y\rangle=\int^b_a xy=\int^b_a yx=\langle y,x\rangle.
 \end{align*}
(iii)
    \begin{align*}
\langle x,x\rangle=\int^b_a x^2\geq 0\quad \text{with equality occuring at}\quad x=0.
\end{align*}
Since the three properties hold, $C[a,b]$ is indeed an inner product space with the inner product defined on $L^2$.

We must now show that the space $C[a,b]$ is not complete with respect to the norm induced by the inner product which is $\|h\|=\sqrt{\langle h,h\rangle}$. We shall write this out as,
$$
\|h\|^2=\left(\int^b_a |h|^2\right).
$$
We need to find some Cauchy sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ such that it does not converge in $C[a,b]$. Consider the sequence of functions defined as,
$$
f_n (x) :=\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if}\;x\geq t,\\
0, & \text{if}\;x\leq t-\frac{1}{n},\\
nx-tn+1, & \text{if}\;t-\frac{1}{n}<x<t,
\end{cases}
$$
where $t\in (a,b)$ is fixed. We know such a function is a continuous function on $[a,b]$. WLOG suppose that $n>m$, we then have
$$
\|f_n-f_m\|_{L_2}^2=\int_{t-\frac{1}{m}}^t |f_n-f_m|^2\,dx\leq \frac{1}{m}<\frac{1}{N}.
$$
We select $N=\left\lceil\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\right\rceil$ and we see that this is indeed a Cauchy Sequence. However, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)$ is actually a discontinuous function. So, this is an example where convergence of a Cauchy sequence in $C[a,b]$ does not converge in $C[a,b]$ and thus, it is not a complete space. Therefore, it is not a Hilbert space.

Comment: Seems correct. Maybe you can also show that limit of these sequence is the indicator function $1_{(t,b)}$. Then there is no doubt that your space isn't complete.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek Is there a way to show that in only a few lines?

Comment: it is more or less the same as your proof for this sequence is a Cauchy sequence.